# Gesture recognizer for UIImageView in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uigesturerecognizer

I added `UIImageView` in superview then add required gestures and works fine but when doing the same in another `UIView` (add `UIImageView` in `UIView` and add gestures) it does not work I think it's about delegates but I can't figure it out.

Code in Swift please.

[image: view hierarchy]

Comment: try using view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: Use this: yourImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Ex-

```
self.imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Add Gesture you want on UIView or ImageView

```
func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let tappedImageView = gestureRecognizer.view!
    let imageView = tappedImageView as! UIImageView
 }
```